# C programming printf("%d %d %d",a,a++,++a); why is the output 5 4 5?

Tags: c

I am a begineer learning C and I dont understand why I am getting this output.
For the order of arguments - I am using gnu so its right to left.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int a = 3;
        printf("%d %d %d", a, a++, ++a);
        return 0;
    }
```

output - 5 4 5
I was expecting - 5 4 4

This is my first Question here I am sorry if its a silly doubt I do know that it is a very small question, but I don't understand it somehow..